# Is it possible to pass a shell variable from linux to windows via winexe?

Tags: shell, unix-shell

I want to pass a shell variable called $test to windows from linux via winexe.

For example:

winexe -W WORKGROUP -U user%password //192.160.13.13 'cmd.exe /C move D:\restore_db\$test D:\Restore\'

Is there any way to do achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `winexe` before, but I don't see why you can't do shell variable substitution in the command line for `winexe` on the *nix side. I think you just need to tweak the shell variable substitution to do what you want and you're set. Double-quotes around your Windows command line containing the $ variable substitution ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Since `winexe` is invoked on Linux, all the usual expansion rules apply. In your example, `$test` will not be expanded because you've enclosed it in single quotes. The literal text `$test` will be passed to `cmd.exe`. If you change the single quotes to double quotes, then `$test` will be expanded prior to it being passed to `cmd.exe`.